# Combinations and their sum with constraints

Tags: summation, permutations, binomial-coefficients, combinations

I have a number of books (n). They all have different a different thickness and mass.

I know that there are (2^n)-1 combinations to place the books. The order of the books does not matter.

However I want to understand what happens when I introduce a constraint into these problem. Such as the fact that a maximum of 6 books are able to be placed next to each other, because 6 x the 6 thinnest books still fits but 7 x the 7 thinnest books does not.

How many possible combinations are there then?

For example if N = 4 (a,b,c,d) we can receive the following options:

> a b c d ab ac ad bc bd cd abc abd acd bcd abcd

which equals to 15 = (2^n)-1 combinations.
Now if my maximum constraint is 2, the results would be:

> a b c d ab ac ad bc bd cd

Which is equal to 10 combinations.
How do I calculate this?

What I am ultimately trying to get to is the most efficient way of placing these books on shelves. but the number of books can go into the hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

There are $2^n-1$ non-empty subsets of the set of books.  This doesn't say anything about the order.

To choose $r$ items out of $n$, again without respect to order, you want ${n\choose r}=\frac {n!}{r!(n-r)!}$

You could see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinations) to start.

Comment: so if my r = 2 in my example. The result would have to be (4 2) + (4 1) = 6 + 4 = 10 which is correct. But my question is the sumation. Is there a general equation for this? or is it just a SUM?